# Referencing a type or class through an enum value?

Tags: kotlin, class, generics, enums

I'm new to Kotlin, thank you for your patience!

I'm working on the code below, to try and figure out if it's possible to associate the enum value defined, with the intended class and type for reference elsewhere, and to use that defined relationship to eliminate the "when" clause from 5 to 1.

The issue I run into is the line referencing types with angle brackets, is there a way or a way around it, using the enum value I've defined?

```
GenericCsvParser<SnowflakeReserveItem>()
```

Where I want to get to is

```
fun persistSnowflakeData(
        inputStream: InputStream,
        dataType: SnowflakeDataType,
    ){ 
        val sfItems = GenericCsvParser<dataType.value>()
        .parse(inputStream, datatype.value)
        .toList()

        snowflakeItemRepository.saveAll(sfItems)
     }
```

The code right now:

```
fun persistSnowflakeData(
        inputStream: InputStream,
        dataType: SnowflakeDataType,
    ) {
        when (dataType) {
            SNOWFLAKE_RESERVE_BOOKING -> {
                val sfItems = GenericCsvParser<SnowflakeReserveItem>()
                    .parse(inputStream, SnowflakeReserveItem::class.java)
                    .toList()
                snowflakeItemRepository.saveAll(sfItems)
            }
            SNOWFLAKE_MEMBERSHIP_TERM -> {
                val sfItems = GenericCsvParser<SnowflakeMembershipTerm>()
                    .parse(inputStream, SnowflakeMembershipTerm::class.java)
                    .toList()
                snowflakeMembershipTermRepository.saveAll(sfItems)
            }
            SNOWFLAKE_MEMBERSHIP_BOOKING -> {
                val sfItems = GenericCsvParser<SnowflakeMembershipOrderBooking>()
                    .parse(inputStream, SnowflakeMembershipOrderBooking::class.java)
                    .toList()
                snowflakeMembershipItemRepository.saveAll(sfItems)
            }
            SNOWFLAKE_OFFLINE_SALE_BOOKING -> {
                val sfItems = GenericCsvParser<SnowflakeOfflineItem>()
                    .parse(inputStream, SnowflakeOfflineItem::class.java)
                    .toList()
                snowflakeOfflineItemRepository.saveAll(sfItems)
            }

            SNOWFLAKE_ONLINE_SALE_BOOKING -> {
                val sfItems = GenericCsvParser<SnowflakeOnlineItem>()
                    .parse(inputStream, SnowflakeOnlineItem::class.java)
                    .toList()
                snowflakeOnlineItemRepository.saveAll(sfItems)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    enum class SnowflakeDataType(clazz: Class<*>) {
        SNOWFLAKE_RESERVE_BOOKING(SnowflakeReserveItem::class.java),
        SNOWFLAKE_MEMBERSHIP_TERM(SnowflakeMembershipTerm::class.java),
        SNOWFLAKE_MEMBERSHIP_BOOKING(SnowflakeMembershipOrderBooking::class.java),
        SNOWFLAKE_OFFLINE_SALE_BOOKING(SnowflakeOfflineItem::class.java),
        SNOWFLAKE_ONLINE_SALE_BOOKING(SnowflakeOnlineItem::class.java)
    }
```

Comment: What is `GenericCsvParser` and `snowflakeItemRepository`?

Comment: I find it difficult to suggest something concrete as It's important to know the code around this. One option would be to model this as a hierarchy with small sealed classes rather than an Enum, as each branch of the `when` calls different methods on the repository. Another would be to create a small generic class that receives the class and a method reference to `*Repository.saveAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`Reified type parameters`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters)

```
interface ItemRepository<T> {
    fun saveAll(item: T)
}

//...

inline fun <reified T> persistSnowflakeData(
    inputStream: InputStream,
    repository: ItemRepository<T>,
) { 
    val items = GenericCsvParser<T>()
        .parse(inputStream, T::class.java)
        .toList()

    repository.saveAll(items)
}
```

`snowflakeItemRepository`, `snowflakeMembershipTermRepository` and others item repositories should implement `ItemRepository`.

Then you can call the function as follows:

```
//...
persistSnowflakeData(inputStream, snowflakeItemRepository)
//...
persistSnowflakeData(inputStream, snowflakeMembershipTermRepository)
//...
```